# How to pull parent taxonomy from nodes

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy list like so...

Parent One
    Subitem One
    SubItem Two
       SubItem Three
Parent Two 
    Subitem Four
Parent Three
    SubItem Five 
    SubItem Six

I also have a content type that uses subitems in a field, along with other fields.

I need to have a view that will show the parent taxonomy terms in addition to the other fields in the CCK.  Something like

Parent Fields
      Title
      Book
      Subotem 1
   Parent Two - SubItemsTwo
      Title
      Book
      Subotem 3

Please advise

Comment: I think an unordered list showing how your taxonomy is structured would help.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [Relationships](https://www.drupal.org/node/1841004) for this.

Comment: I agree, however can you expand? I'm playing with relationships but I must have it incorrect.  I'm not able to pull the parent back in the view